# Adding dummy variable with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called "insider_dataset" composed as follows:

```
personid cusip6 acqdisp trandate   month  year
     <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 13080542 143436 D       2000-01-03     1  2000
2 12260711 143436 A       2002-01-07     1  2002
3 12700206 143436 D       2010-10-03    10  2010
4     7161 382388 A       2011-09-03     9  2011
5     7161 382388 A       2012-09-08     9  2012
6     7161 382388 A       2013-09-03     9  2013
```

My aim is to add a dummy variable called "routine_dummmy" equal to 1 if the personid is appearing with the same acqdisp and the same month in the two years preceding trandate, and equal to zero otherwise. In the example the dummy variable would be equal to 1 only in row 6. What i tried is:

```
while (i <= nrow(insider_dataset)) {
  if (nrow(subset(insider_dataset, personid == insider_dataset$personid[i]
                  & month == month[i] & year == year[i]-1 | year == year[i]-2 & acqdisp == 
                  acqdisp[i])) > 1) {
    insider_dataset$routine_dummy[i] <- 1
  }
  else insider_dataset$routine_dummy[i] <- 0
  i <- i+1
}
```

Which appears to work, but it is very slow in my very large datasets. Is there a more compact and efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops are not efficient in `R` that's why you need to opt for vectorised operations (using `data.table` if you really want some speed). Also if you want to check that it exist in the two preceding years change `any` => `all`

#### `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
 group_by(personid, acqdisp, month) %>%
 mutate(routine_dummmy = +sapply(year[row_number()],function(x) any((x-1:2) %in% year) ))
# A tibble: 7 x 7
# Groups:   personid, acqdisp, month [4]
  personid cusip6 acqdisp trandate   month routine_dummmy  year
     <int>  <int> <fct>   <fct>      <int>          <int> <int>
1 13080542 143436 D       2000-01-03     1              0  2000
2 12260711 143436 A       2002-01-07     1              0  2002
3 12700206 143436 D       2010-10-03    10              1  2010
4     7161 382388 A       2011-09-03     9              0  2011
5     7161 382388 A       2012-09-08     9              1  2012
6     7161 382388 A       2013-09-03     9              1  2013
7 12700206 143436 D       2008-10-03    10              0  2008
```

#### `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)
dt[, 
    routine_dummmy:=sapply(1:.N, function(I) +any((year[I]-1:2) %in% year)), by=.(personid, acqdisp, month)
][]

   personid cusip6 acqdisp   trandate month routine_dummmy year
1: 13080542 143436       D 2000-01-03     1              0 2000
2: 12260711 143436       A 2002-01-07     1              0 2002
3: 12700206 143436       D 2010-10-03    10              1 2010
4:     7161 382388       A 2011-09-03     9              0 2011
5:     7161 382388       A 2012-09-08     9              1 2012
6:     7161 382388       A 2013-09-03     9              1 2013
7: 12700206 143436       D 2008-10-03    10              0 2008
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `data.table` solution that I think will be relatively fast.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(insider_dataset)

insider_dataset[, diff := c(0, diff(year)), by = c('personid', 'acqdisp', 'month')][,
  routine_dummy := +(diff == 1 & lag(diff) == 1), by = c('personid', 'acqdisp', 'month')]

insider_dataset
```

**Output**

```
   personid cusip6 acqdisp   trandate month year diff routine_dummy
1: 13080542 143436       D 2000-01-03     1 2000    0             0
2: 12260711 143436       A 2002-01-07     1 2002    0             0
3: 12700206 143436       D 2010-10-03    10 2010    0             0
4:     7161 382388       A 2011-09-03     9 2011    0             0
5:     7161 382388       A 2012-09-08     9 2012    1             0
6:     7161 382388       A 2013-09-03     9 2013    1             1
```